# 3D Rotation without Trigonometry?

Tags: math, vector

I am developing a rotate-around-axis algorithm in 3 dimensions. My inputs are

- the axis I am revolving around, as a vector from my center point
- the center point (obviously)
- the angle I wish to rotate around
- my current position

I am wondering if there is a way to do this without trigonometry, just with vector operations. Does anyone have a potential solution?

**EDIT:** Is there a way that I could rotate by pi/4 radians (45 degrees) each time, rather than an inputted angle theta? This might simplify things a bit, I don't know.

Comment: What vector operations do you have available?

Comment: I have cross, dot, add, subtract, and normalize available.

Comment: In that case I have a pretty strong feeling you can't implement a rotation without using trigonometry in some form. You might be able to get away with one trig function evaluation, the cosine (or sine) of the rotation angle, but you have to have at least the one. The only case in which you could do without that would be if you had a "rotation" vector operation available (and even then, it would probably be doing trig behind the scenes).

Comment: Is there a way to find a perpendicular and cut it? Possibly?

Comment: You need trig functions to do that too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rotations are inherently well-described by [image: \sin] and [image: \cos].

It's a handy trick that unit [quaternion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html)s nicely represent 3-D rotations just as well as (and in some senses, better than) rotation matrices.  Converting a rotation by angle [image: \theta] about a normal axis [image: \hat n=\left<x,y,z\right>] where [image: x^2+y^2+z^2=1], does require a little bit of trigonometry: [image: \left(\cos\left(\frac12\theta\right)\right)+\left(x\sin\left(\frac12\theta\right)\right)i+\left(y\sin\left(\frac12\theta\right)\right)j+\left(z\sin\left(\frac12\theta\right)\right)k].

But from there on it's simple arithmetic.
A quaternion [image: q=a+bi+cj+dk] can be directly applied to rotate a vector with [image: q(xi+yj+zk)q^{-1}], or  converted to a rotation matrix [image: \left(\begin{matrix}a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2&2bc-2ad&2bd+2ac\2bc+2ad&a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2&2cd-2ab\2bd-2ac&2cd+2ab&a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2\end{matrix}\right)].

This is a rotation around the origin, of course.  To rotate around an arbitrary point [image: o] in space, simply translate by [image: -o] to the origin, rotate, then translate by [image: o] to return.

Comment: Excellent! Quaternions are really very useful with describing 3D rotations!

Answer (score 3):

If this is some sort of dumb homework problem, you can use [Taylor Series approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence) of the sine/consine functions. Whether or not this "counts" as trigonometry is I guess up for debate.  You could then use these values in a rotation matrix or quarternion, if you want to use vector operations.

But again, there's no practical reason to do this.

Comment: This question is just to see if there's any way to avoid trig. I know about the Taylor Series, I'm just trying to see if there's any other way.

Answer (score 2):

use matrices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_three_dimensions

Comment: Those matrix operations use trig (although I don't see a way to do this in any reasonable fashion without it).

Comment: Rotation matrices still use sin() and cos() though.  I don't really see anything involving rotation avoiding these computations though.

Comment: true. it is a rotation at some angle. i can't think of a way that does not involve those.

Answer (score 1):

Are there other techniques that don't use trig functions?  Possibly, but there are no know efficient, general (i.e. for arbitrary angles) ways to perform rotations without use of trig functions.

However, based on your edit, you can precompute the `sin` and `cos` for a collection of angles you're interested in and store them in a lookup table.  You need not be constrained in such a circumstance to `π/4` increments, but you can do `π/256` or `π/1024` increments if you want.  Also, you don't need two tables, since `cos(θ) = sin(θ+π/2)`.

From there, you can use any of a number of interpolation methods to include simple rounding, linear interpolation or some sort of polynomial interpolation based on your needs.

You would then use either the matrix or quaternion based transformation to compute the rotated vector.

This will be faster than computing the `sin` and `cos` for general angles, though will require some additional space, and there will be an accuracy penalty as well.  But if it satisfies your needs...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to rotate without trigonometry? Yes.

Is it useful to rotate without using trigonometry? Probably not.

---

The first option is a problem-level solution: Change your coordinate system to [spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) or [cylindrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) coordinates.

Since you rotate around an axis cylindrical coordinates of the form `(alpha, radius, x3)` will work.

Naming your center point `O` (for origin) and the point to rotate `P`, you can get the vector between them `v=P-O`. You also know the normal vector `n` of your plane of rotation (the vector you rotate around). With this, you can get the components of `v` that are parallel and orthogonal to `n` using a [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

You have the freedom to choose how your new coordinate frame is rotated (relative to your original frame), so you can measure angles from the projection of `v` onto the plane of rotation. You also have the freedom to choose between degree and radians.

From there, you can now rotate to your heart's content using addition and subtraction.

Using `dot(.,.)` to denote the scalar product it would look something like this in code

```
v_parallel = dot(v, n) / dot(n, n) * n
radius = norm(v - v_parallel)
x3 = norm(v_parallel)

new_axis = (v - v_parallel) / norm(v - v_parallel)
P_polar = (0, radius, x3)

# P rotated by 90 degrees
P_polar = (pi/2, radius, x3)

# P rotated by -10 degrees
P_polar = (-pi/36, radius, x3)
```

However, if you want to change back to a standard basis you will have to use trigonometry again. Hence why I said this approach exists, but may not be too useful in practice.

---

Another approach comes from the cool observation that you can describe any planar rotation using two reflections along two given axis (represented by two vectors). The plane of rotation is the plane that is spun up by the two vectors and the angle of rotation is *twice* the angle between the two vectors.

You can reflect a vector using the [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) from above; hence, you can do the entire process without trigonometry if you know the two vectors (let's call them `x1` and `x2`).

```
tmp = v - 2 * dot(v, x1) / dot(x1, x1) * x1
v_rotated = tmp - 2 * dot(tmp, x2) / dot(x2, x2) * x2
```

The problem then turns into finding two vectors that are orthogonal to `n` and have an enclosing angle of `alpha/2`. How to do this is specific to your problem. For arbitrary alpha this is again the point where you can't dodge the trigonometry bullet; hence, it is again possible, but maybe not so viable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

With help from Mathematica, it looks like we can rotate a point around a vector without Sin/Cos if you are willing to specify the amount of rotation as a number between -1 and 1, rather than an angle in radians.

The below starts with Mathematica's RotationTransform of a point {x,y,z} around a vector {u,v,w} by c radians (which contains many instances of Cos[c] and Sin[c]). It then substitutes all the Cos[c] with "c" and Sin[c] with Sqrt[1-c^2] (a trig identity for Sin in terms of Cos). Everything is simplified with the assumption that the rotation vector is normalized. The resulting equation produces the rotated point without any trig operations.

[image: Screenshot showing Mathematica command producing rotation equation]

Note: as c ranges from -1 to 1 the point will only rotate through half a circle, the other half of the rotation can be achieved by flipping the signs on {u,v,w}.

Comment: Here is text/CForm for easier cut/paste. (x + (-1 + c)*Power(v,2)*x + (-1 + c)*Power(w,2)*x + 
    Sqrt(1 - Power(c,2))*(-(w*y) + v*z) - (-1 + c)*u*(v*y + w*z),
   Sqrt(1 - Power(c,2))*w*x + u*v*(x - c*x) + c*y + Power(v,2)*(y - c*y) - 
    Sqrt(1 - Power(c,2))*u*z + v*w*(z - c*z),
   -(Sqrt(1 - Power(c,2))*v*x) + u*w*(x - c*x) + Sqrt(1 - Power(c,2))*u*y + 
    v*w*(y - c*y) + c*z + Power(w,2)*(z - c*z))

Answer (score 0):

Theres a cheaper way than matrices,  I think ive got it to sum count of adders.

The perimetre box of the vector is as good as an angle, if you step in partitions of the box size. (thats only a binary shift if its a power of 2.)

Then that would be a "box rotate" then just use the side report to give you how far along the diagonal you would be then you can split it up into so many gradients, the circle shape.

Id like to see someone proove that u can rotate without matrices or any trig like that too.